# Conditions with grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show a grouped_collection_select with my Products (a product is linked to a category) so I made this :

```
<%= c.grouped_collection_select :product_id, @categories, :products, :name, :id, :combined_name, :include_blank => true %>
```

But I just want some products which have a boolean to "true", is it possible to specify this ? I know that it is possible with @categories but I don't know with :products...

Thanks